# Animation.css doesn't animate. Instead just add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The Goal: On scroll I need Jquery to add a class of animated slideInUp to a form that is at the bottom of my page using Animate.css. If you look at the Css I tried to hide the icon off the screen before I got down to the bottom then the idea would be that it reveal itself once jquery kicked in.
I got it working once using Bootstrap 3 and now that I'm using the Just Bootrap 3 Grid, it isn't working anymore(Might be unrelated)...Like it literally worked yesterday. It def adds the class, "animated slideInUp" , but doesn't slide, It just appears.

HTML:

```
div class="row">
<div class="container" id="load-form">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
//Bunch of icons//
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h5>Sign up for our monthly newsletter!</h5>
                <span id="form"><?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="208" title="Email NewsLetter"]'); ?></span>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wpcf7-form { //this is the class gets auto outputted by the plugin.
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;  //trying to give it a padding top so element has room to "slide up"
}
.animated { // this is the class that is animated.css
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {//Must add no-conflict cause Wordpress
var locateForm = $('#load-form');
  var formLocateOrigOffsetY = locateForm.offset().top;

  function scrollForm() {
   if ($(document).scrollTop() >= formLocateOrigOffsetY) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $('.wpcf7-form').addClass('animated slideInUp');
        }, 500);
          }
       }

 $(document).on('scroll', scrollForm);

});//End No conflict
```

Side Note: The animation is no longer hiding then sliding up as it did before. I have link jquery the right way... For those familiar with WordPress:

```
function theme_js() {
      //Other things that I have enqueued//

    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
```

**For those that are gonna say something about this is how this isn't the WordPress section, frig off, Im just trying to provide as much info possible.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Did you include the animate.css file?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm as in your code js file is enqueued